# I cannot get this xml containing TabHost to load correctly in an android application

Tags: java, android, xml, tabs, android-tabhost

Does anyone know why this wont load correctly.  I get a force quit in the emulator when it tries loading this xml. I am trying to set the layout to this TabHost.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#FFFFFF">
  <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="10px" android:layout_marginBottom="10px">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="10px" android:src="@drawable/logo"></ImageView>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center">
            <TextView android:text="text" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Text1" android:textColor="#1565BC" android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="text" android:id="@+id/Text2" android:textColor="#333333"></TextView>
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="text" android:id="@+id/Text3" android:textColor="#333333"></TextView>
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="text" android:id="@+id/Text4" android:textColor="#333333"></TextView>
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="text" android:id="@+id/Text5" android:textColor="#1565BC"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
  <TabWidget 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_below="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tableRow1"/>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: You should post the Exception that you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I just used your layout without any trouble at all, the only thing I changed

```
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/mylogo"></ImageView>
```

Check your entries in the drawable folders, that might be the problem.

Comment: the layout works but when i run it in the emulator it force quits. Can I not add this layout to an emulator running 2.3.3 maybe? Does TabHost only work with 3.0

Comment: the link for TabHost http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html  again it worked fine in 2.3.3